# LWJGL and Scala, drawing an object

Tags: scala, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am working on a project that I am writing in Scala and I am using the LWJGL and I am having some issues making an object appear onscreen. I have used LWJGL with java in the past so I tried to write pretty much the same code but in scala.

Here is my main class that initializes the window

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils
import org.lwjgl.glfw.{GLFWErrorCallback, GLFWKeyCallback}
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW._
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11._
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15._


object Main {
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    init()
    loop()
}
var window:Long = 0
val height = 720
val width = 1280
def init()= {
//Set up error callback to print to System.err
GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set()

//Init window
if (!glfwInit())
  throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to init GLFW")

glfwDefaultWindowHints()
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE,GLFW_FALSE)   //window stays hidden after 
creation
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GLFW_TRUE)  //window will be resizable

//Create window
window = glfwCreateWindow(width,height,"Platformer",0,0)
if (window == 0) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create window")
}

glfwSetInputMode(window,GLFW_STICKY_KEYS,1)
//Set escape key callback to close window
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window: Long, key: Int, scancode: Int, action: Int, mods: Int) => {
  if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true)
  }
})

//Make the context current
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)

//Enable v-sync
glfwSwapInterval(1)

//Show window
glfwShowWindow(window)
//Allows gl calls
GL.createCapabilities()

//Set clear color and get ready for textures
glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glOrtho(0,1280,720,0,1, 0 - 1)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

//Allows use of alpha values
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
}

def loop(): Unit ={
  val obj = new RenderObject()
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
      glfwPollEvents()
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
      obj.render()
      glfwSwapBuffers(window)
  }
}

//I tested this method and it works properly
def createBuffer(floats:Array[Float]):FloatBuffer = {
  var buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(floats.length)
  buffer.put(floats)
  buffer.flip()
  buffer
 }
}
```

And here is my RenderObject

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15._
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11._

class RenderObject(){
  var vId: Int = glGenBuffers()
  protected var vertices:Array[Float] = Array(
    0,0,
    0,1000,
    1000,1000,
    0,1000
  )
init()
def init(): Unit ={
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vId)
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Main.createBuffer(vertices),GL_STATIC_DRAW)
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)
}

//Renders the object
def render(): Unit ={
  //Put this in to test the buffer data
  var floatArray:Array[Float] = new Array[Float](12)
  glGetBufferSubData(vId,0,floatArray)
  for (f <- floatArray) println(f+"")
  //Always prints out 0.0

  glColor3f(1,0,0)

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vId)
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)

  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

 }
}
```

I put in glGetBufferSubData to test if the buffer has my data and it always just prints out 0.0. This leads me to believe the error has something to do with my init function in RenderObject. Does anyone have any ideas I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of [`glGetBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetBufferSubData.xhtml) is the target and not the object name. You have to do it like this:

```
var floatArray:Array[Float] = new Array[Float](8)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vId)
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, floatArray)
```

But you can use [`glGetNamedBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetBufferSubData.xhtml), too:

```
glGetNamedBufferSubData(vId, 0, floatArray)
```

Further, the vertex coordinates do not form a quad. The coordinate (0, 1000) is twice, but the coordinate (1000, 0) is missing. Change your code like this:

```
protected var vertices:Array[Float] = Array(
    0,    0,
    0,    1000,
    1000, 1000,
    1000, 0
)
```